# Need explanation about requesting permission for notifications in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter, unusernotification

[Info about "authorization"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW1)

[Info about "requesting permission"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1)

The problem is they both needed in the same code but they are split into 2 separate articles. So it is unclear how to deal with them simultaneously and what is the difference between them (of course except of input params).

The code I found just calls these functions sequentially:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: { granted, error in
  ...
})
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Is it correct? And what is the difference between these methods?

P.S. I also can't simply place them inside `application:didFinishLoad:` according to the documentation because the app shouldn't request permissions from the very first run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: { granted, error in
  ...
  // code here
})
```

Asks the user whether he accepts receive notification which actually will show the popup , but this ( used for push notifications not local )

```
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

According to [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623078-registerforremotenotifications)

> Call this method to initiate the registration process with Apple
>   Push Notification service. If registration succeeds, the app calls
>   your app delegate object’s
>   application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: method
>   and passes it a device token.

//

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })

    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

} else {
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Comment: from your link to docs: `If you want your app’s remote notifications to display alerts, play sounds, or perform other user-facing actions, you must request authorization to do so using the requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler:) method of UNUserNotificationCenter.` but they don't describe how to call it. I need badge/sound/banner for notification but if so then should I call `registerForRemoteNotifications` if I don't use `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`?